# importing data from multiple databases using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I want to import certain tables from multiple SQLsever databases(100+) using sqoop to HDFS. Can someone guide me how to do it? an automated script would do well.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by shell script.

1)Prepare a inputfile which has list of DBNAME.TABLENAME
2)The shell script will have this file as input, iterate line by line and execute sqoop statement for each line.

```
while read line;
do

    DBNAME=`echo $line | cut -d'.' -f1` 
    tableName=`echo $line | cut -d'.' -f2`


    sqoop import -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=$RM_QUEUE_NAME --connect '$JDBC_URL;databaseName=$DBNAME;username=$USERNAME;password=$PASSWORD' --table $tableName  --target-dir $DATA_COLLECTOR/$tableName  --fields-terminated-by '\001'  -m 1 

done<inputFile
```