# Sqoop import remaining tables into HDFS

Tags: sql, hdfs, sqoop

I have a database that contains about 830 tables. I tried doing a sqoop import-all-tables and it imported about 150 tables and failed on one table.

1. Is there a way for me to specify exclusions in the sqoop command?
2. How do I sqoop import the remaining 680 tables? When i use the same sqoop command, it fails as it specifies that some tables are already exisiting?

Here is the sqoop command used:

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.169.108.64;database=axios; username=XXXXX;password=XXXXXXXXXX" --warehouse-dir=/user/Axios -m 1
```

Comment: you can try --exclude-tables with sqoop import-all-tables option

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910899/importing-data-from-multiple-databases-using-sqoop/34943031#34943031